# Regular expression allow commas

Tags: javascript, expression, validation

I need to allow only letters and some chars.
I use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z '-_]*)$")
```

But this allows also `, ; : .`

Why?

Comment: You don't match start to end, you could try to insert a heading `^` (anchor for beginning of input).

Answer (score 2):

A hyphen (`-`) inside of a character class designates a range, you should escape this with a backslash by changing `[a-zA-Z '-_]` to the following:

```
[a-zA-Z '\-_]
```

Without this the regex engine will interpret `'-_` as a range of characters from `'` to `_`, which would include the following characters (http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ 
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
```

You will probably also want to add a `^` to the start and `$` to the end of your regex, these are beginning and end of string anchors and they will prevent your regex from matching only part of a string.

Comment: -1 This is produce also true cause there is no bound ^$ and + to set one or more characters

Comment: I interpreted the OP's issue as "the regex is matching commas", which would no longer be possible after escaping the hyphen.  Anyway I added a note about anchors in an edit (and by the way, I am not the one that downvoted your answer).

Comment: If you want to match `-` you can also put it unescaped as the very first character in `[]` like `/^[-a-z]+$/.test('a-little-thing')`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I cannot make it to work :( What is wrong:

    function checkField(fieldValue){
        var RegExPattern = "([a-zA-Z '\-_])$";
        if (fieldValue.match(RegExPattern)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
Allow numbers, commas, etc.

Comment: Try using `var RegExPattern = /^[a-zA-Z '\-_]*$/`.  Without the `^` anchor at the beginning you will only be testing the characters at the end of the string.

Comment: why do you use `match` and not `test` if all you have to do is return boolean ? look at my answer below for the correct way to regexp validate in js

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `^` on the start and `$` at the end to force it be only that group:

```
/^[a-zA-Z \'\-_]+$/.test('Adidi:') // false
```